# Are there any (GUI) tools for MongoDB use Mongoose like syntax?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, user-interface, mongoose

I'm new to both Node.js and MongoDB. I'm using **Mongoose** to do the query and aggregation. Mongoose's syntax is a bit different to native MongoDB. I'm looking for kind of tools, GUI tools is better, to test my Mongoose query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give [mongobooster](http://www.mongobooster.com) a try. Mongobooster support mongoose-like fluent query builder which enables you to build up a query using chaining syntax, rather than specifying a JSON object.

```
// instead of writing:
db.user.find({age:{:18,:65}},{name,1,age:1,_id:-1}).sort({age:-1, name:1});

// we can write:
db.user.where('age').gte(18).lte(65).select('name age -_id').sort("-age name");    

// passing query conditions is permitted too
db.collection.find().where({ name: 'mongobooster' })

// chaining
db.collection
        .where('age').gte(18).lte(65)
        .where({ 'name': /^mongobooster/i })
        .where('friends').slice(10)

// aggregation
db.companies.aggregate(qb.where('founded_year').gte(2000).lte(2010)) //qb:querybuilder
      .group({_id:"$category_code",count:{$sum:1}})
      .sort('-count')
      .limit(100)
```

http://www.mongobooster.com

Answer (score 2):

It's not very much different though..

I have used [RoboMongo](https://robomongo.org/download). But I think it supports only `Mongodb` not `Mongoose`.